# What weest sole change would have actualized High Speed Rail in Canada?

Tags: alternate-history

I was startled that [Canada is the only G7 country without a high-speed rail system, and this in spite of the fact that the huge distances between cities make it a worthwhile endeavour.](https://www.rcinet.ca/en/2018/02/15/high-speed-rail-promised-for-canada-again/)

Your high speed train (HST) must be [currently or no longer in service](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_high-speed_trains). **The HST should max speed as much as  practicable, to save time.** The HST can lower speed, to abate noise and comply with noise regulations in residential areas.
No experimental trains.

Your answer can address just two corridors **(1)** [Edmonton — Red Deer — Calgary corridors, and *(2)* Windsor — London — Toronto — Ottawa — Montreal— Quebec City](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-speed_rail_in_Canada) . Saskatchewan, Manitoba, Northern Ontario, Eastern Quebec, and Maritimes are too sparsely populated for coast to coast HSR. Therefore I don't expect transnational HSR in your answer, but don't hesitate to argue the best case for it.
[image]

### More Fanciful Map.

[image]

Comment: That's a little tougher than the USA. especially the transcontinental part. Lou population density is tough.

Comment: You have not defined "High Speed Rail." There are many possible definitions. The [UIC](https://uic.org/) has a very lax standard that I personally reject: 250kmh in new construction, but as low as 200kmh in older...permitting modest efforts like the NYC-Washington corridor to call itself "high speed" despite it's end-to-end average of a piddling 125kmh. By that (awful-but-common) definition, the Windsor-Quebec corridor is already very close to High Speed.

Comment: The cost of building high speed rail through the Canadian Rockies would be prohibitive. It was expensive enough to build slow speed rail through them. High speed needs far gentler curves and grades.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can count the US as the second country without high speed rail. even though there is some of it. it is whoefully inadequate. a bunch of things are contributing to this lack of high speed rail in north america.

1. car dependency
2. great aeroplane network
3. low population density
4. low fuel cost

major parts of north america are built for cars. you are expected to drive to work, school, shops, friends and leisure activities. this gets everyone in a car before they even look for public transport. making public transport more difficult to become profitable.

for long to medium distances there is an existing competing mode of transportation. namely the aviation network. its advantage is that it exists in our current day. and that the setup costs are about the same for any distance travelled. just 2 airports and a plane. trains ant their stations may not be so expensive but the miles and miles of track do add up.

the amount of people interested per mile is lower due to the low-ish average population density. compared to countries in Europa and Japan. this favours the lower setup costs for aviation.

lastly the cost of fuel. the running costs of the aviation industry is highly dependant on fuel cost unlike rail. so is driving everywhere to a lesser extend. north america is famous for its cheep fuel. the US even more so. if i were to change one thing then it would be to increase the cost of fuel dramatically and irreversibly. people will want to share those fuel costs and demand public transport including high-speed rail. lots of other things will change as well. like where and how people will want to live. more walking and biking in stead of driving. etc.

Comment: Another factor is how quickly people move residence. That means that transportation systems that are faster to reconfigure are preferred. When it takes 20 years to build a railroad and in that time, a city has sprung up and is already declining, that makes it hard to justify a rail.

Comment: @DavidR do towns grow and decay that fast over there in Canada? if i recall there is the concept of rail station towns. towns that form around rail stations because of the easy connection to other parts of the country and the cheaper costs for housing. similar to an suburb but this time built around a train station.

Comment: I can't speak for Canada, but that speed has happened in the US. You are correct in that a number of towns have sprung up around rail stations. There are also quite a number of rail roads that have been abandoned and the towns decayed throughout rural US. A rail line can be built to a new mining town and abandoned very quickly when the ore runs out.

Comment: The "cheap fuel" option can go another way as well: the Quebec-Windsor corridor starts, obviously, in Quebec. Hydro-Quebec is the third largest hydroelectric power producer in the world. Residential electricity in Quebec is the cheapest in the country. So if you electrify the corridor, you're already plugged into some of the cheapest electricity in North America.

Answer (score 2):

1919-1923: Corridor Preservation

When the Grand Trunk Railway, National Transcontinental Railway, Canadian Government Railway, and other bankrupt/overbuilt projects were merged into CN, some duplicate lines fell into disuse and were eventually abandoned.

Had duplicate lines been preserved by the Crown for (subsidized) passenger use in the 1920s, they would be available for upgrading in the 1970 and 1980s. With routes signaled for passenger service and few freight conflicts, the (subsidized) 1980s [LRC trains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LRC_(train)) could have affordably achieved the regular-service 200kmh that they were designed for.

If a successful decade of LRC operation could demonstrate safe, reliable, 200kmh operation, and recover operating costs, one imagines in the 1990s that Transport Canada might tender for franchise the Quebec-Windsor alignment, attracting the private capital needed for electrification, for infrastructure upgrades to 300kmh, and for the HSR trainsets.

The other potential corridor is Calgary-Edmonton. That's a bit too small of a market to justify real 300kmh HSR, but large enough for less-expensive, non-HSR 200kmh LRC (and successor) service. The rest of the lines of the map are fanciful.

But back to the fun corridor...

One can also imagine that around 2005, Transport Canada might realign the western approach to Toronto with a new HSR station at Pearson Airport. A very expensive project, but surprisingly popular with MPs in Ottawa willing to pay for it (and who get much better flight options from the 90-minute train ride).

One imagines that today, Virgin Trains would run hourly 300kmh service in the Quebec-Windsor corridor. The first generation of HSR trainsets would have been retired five years ago after 20 years of service, and the current generation to be over 90% built in Canada. An international station at Detroit (and Detroit Airport) would have been under discussion with the Americans for 15 years without notable progress, as would be the proposed branch to Niagara Falls. There would be chat about improving the corridor to 350kmh, but Virgin would balk, saying the time saving just doesn't justify the cost (they're probably right). One imagines Virgin to be mildly profitable, and there's a bit of grumbling about those profits going overseas, but the Crown owns the alignment and the service is good.